# Angularjs directive wrapping ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

An Angularjs newbie here.

I'm trying to use the [Justified gallery](http://miromannino.com/projects/justified-gallery/) in my Angularjs application.

Here is the [JS Fiddle describing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/hqt4W/4/)

Justified gallery is a jquery plugin, so I have created the directive to call it:

```
app.directive('justified', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            $(el).justifiedGallery();
        }
    };
});
```

and indeed it works nicely with statically defined content (like for example the commented out part of the html in the fiddle). But once I try to use it with ng-repeat, like here:

```
   <div justified id="justified"> 
        <a ng-repeat="dir in dirs" ng-href="/#/dir/{{dir.id}}">
          <img ng-src="{{dir.first_image}}" alt="{{dir.name}}"/>
        </a>
    </div justified>
```

nothing happens, nothing gets rendered. I believe it has something to do with the scope within the ng-repeat, but I can't figure out proper approach to the problem.

Could anyone please point me, where's the error I'm making?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom directive to find out when a repeat is finished rendering e.g. from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071221/get-ng-repeat-complete-in-angular-directive)

```
app.directive('repeatDone', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {
          var parentScope = element.parent().scope();
          if (scope.$last){
               parentScope.$last = true;           
          }
        }
      };
    }]);
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjZ8N/1.

**EDIT**
I had to add in a $timeout so that angular could update the html before calling the gallery function.

Comment: Thank you a lot! One question though -- what are the n and o parameters in the function passed to $watch?

Comment: @mkowalik - The function gets two parameters from Angular - the new values and the old values. We want to set up the gallery when the 'n'ew value is true. Make sense?

Comment: absolutely does. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue, and exactly this solution helped.

Comment: Why are you guarding with 'if(scope.$last)' shouldn't this guard with 'if(parentScope)' since that is what you are operating on?

Comment: @catalyst294 - it's not a guard.

Comment: @RobH can you elaborate? I found this code in my project and periodically parentScope is not defined. I had to add parentScope to the if condition to avoid errors.

Comment: @catalyst294 - ah I see. It's not currently supposed to be guarding access to the parent scope, that's assumed to exist. It's saying, if we're on the last item, tell the parent scope. If the parent scope can not exist then adding a guard for that (as you have done) seems very sensible.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple way](http://jsfiddle.net/hqt4W/5/):

```
app.directive('justified', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            $timeout($(el).justifiedGallery);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Seems like it justifiedGallery initiates before ng-repeat finishes rendering elements.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it already and tried to manually set the directive priorities - ng-repeat has priority of 1000, so I set justified to lower value, but it didn't help. btw, I have I modified [your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hqt4W/7/) ( $timeout($(el).justifiedGallery()); instead of  $timeout($(el).justifiedGallery); ), but unfortunately to no avail..

Comment: I think, it would help if `justified` and `ng-repeat` were appended to the same element.

Comment: $timeout accepts a function and executes it after timeout (which is 0 in this case). If you do `$timeout($(el).justifiedGallery());` – you execute `justifiedGallery` immediately and pass it's return value to $timeout - there is no use.

Comment: Thanks for explanation - it makes sense, and I have to admit I haven't read documentation for $timeout.

Comment: This code doesn't work, and your jsfiddle doesn't work. You need to use `$timeout($(el).justifiedGallery.bind($(el)));` or `$timeout($.fn.justifiedGallery.bind($(el)));`