# AngularJS and JQuery justified

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to do what has been answered in this thread:

[Angularjs directive wrapping ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361576/angularjs-directive-wrapping-ng-repeat)

I can get it to work as in the thread, but if I update dirs array using angular (ng-click change the array) the justified gallery is not updated. Does anyone know how to make the directive refresh the page when the dirs array is updated?

UPDATE
Solved it by creating this directive:

```
directive('justified', ['$timeout',function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {
        scope.$watch('myModel', function(){
             $timeout(function () { $(element).justifiedGallery(); });
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Please try again to write a good question. If you need some help, you can read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We have no idea what is wrong with your code, and without more details, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To force the angular scope to update you can run `$scope.apply()` but it is an expensive method so use it with caution

```
app.directive('repeatDone', [function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
 link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {
      var parentScope = element.parent().scope();
      if (scope.$last){
           parentScope.$last = true;           
      }
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
      })
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't work all the time. If I change the scope the first time it works, but not the second time.

Comment: Try instead of doing $scope, do `scope.$apply()` and `parentScope.$apply()`

Comment: same issue. It works the first time the scope is updated but the scope is not updated the second time

Comment: unusual.. did you try it without the `$timeout`